# Code igniter form validation before opening modal window

Tags: ajax, forms, codeigniter, validation, modal-dialog

I currently have a form that I wish to implement form validation for. I'm using the code igniter framework.

When I click the submit form button, the form doesn't submit then, instead a modal window pops up with the information the user has just entered( sort of like confirmation that they have entered the correct details.) 
When the user clicks ok in the modal window the form then submits through ajax and another modal window pops up to confirm the form has been submitted.

What I'm looking to do is validate the form before the first modal window pops up but I can't seem to find a way to do so. Does anyone know how I can do this?

This is my form:

```
<?php if(isset($error)){
echo "<i>" . $error . "</i>";
}?>
<form id ="form1" name ="form1">
    <div class="hospital_container">
        <h3 class = "hospital_header"><b>Enter Hospital Information</b></h3>

    <label for="hospitalName"  id ="hospLabel" class = "labelForm">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class = "input2" id="hospitalName" name="hospitalName" class = "newUserForm">

        <button type="button"  id = "hospital_submit_button" class = "hospital_submit_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userModal">Add New Hospital</button> // triggers the modal window but I want to run form validation before this.

    </div>
</form>
```

Ajax for submit:

```
     $(function() {
//#overlaysubclass2 is the name of the submit button in the modal window
            $("#overlaysubclass2").on("click", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var DataString=$("#form1").serialize()
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Admin/createHospital",
                    type: "post",
                    data:DataString ,
                    success: function(data) {

                        $("#userModal").modal('hide'); // hide the original modal and show the confirmation modal
                        $("#confirmModal").modal('show');
                    }


                });
            });
        });
```

My controller:

```
 function createHospital(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('hospitalName', 'hospitalName', 'required');
  //  $this->form_validation->set_rules('hospAddress', 'hospAddress', 'required');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $data['error'] = 'Please fill in the form';
        $this->load->view('includes/admin/header');
       $this->load->view('newHospital');

    }else {
        $data = array(

            'hospitalName' => $this->input->post('hospitalName'),
        );

        $this->user_model->create_hospital($data);
      //$data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
        $this->load->view('newHospital');
    }
}
```

The form validation isn't actually running though its allowing me to submit a blank form

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm really stuck!

Comment: In my opinion validation is pointless until you are ready to save data to the database.  With your work flow the field data will have to be passed to the server twice - once to validate it and a second time to save it. In other words, you will need two ajax calls; one that handles the form submit when `#hospital_submit_button`is clicked and a second to save the data if `#overlaysubclass2` is clicked. Keep in mind that each ajax call creates a whole new instance of the CodeIgniter framework. Do you really want to be hitting your server that hard?

Comment: Yeah I suppose your right @DFriend .. I've decided to do some manual form validation using JQuery and Javascript instead! Thanks for the advice though!

Answer (score 0):

"The form validation isn't actually running though its allowing me to submit a blank form" actually you don't know if your validation running correctly.

First you need to put your response (from ajax call to: createHospital  method):

```
$("#confirmModal").html(data);  // this line put your response html to '#confirmModal' dom elem.
$("#confirmModal").modal('show');
```

Second better option for this:

```
$("#overlaysubclass2").on("click", function(event) {
```

is:

```
$("#form1").on("submit", function(event) {
```

or:

```
$("#hospital_submit_button").on("click", function(event) {
```

Comment: hey @paweIn ! thanks for the response. I need the form validation to take place before the first modal window though, rather than the confirmation modal. Would you know how I would go about it that way? Thanks again!